# White rectangle covering hot question in Android app feed

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

I noticed a small white rectangle over the title of the hot question displayed in the feed:

> [image]

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: What device? app version?

Comment: It's an LG G5 - version is 1.0.85